# Spark write parquet job completed but have a long delay to start new job

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr, parquet

I am running Spark 2.4.4 on AWS EMR and experienced a long delay after the spark write parquet file to S3. I checked the S3 write process should be completed in few seconds (data files and _success file found in the S3). But it still delayed around 5 mins to start the following jobs.

I saw someone said this is called "Parquet Tax". I have tried the proposed fixes from those articles but still cannot resolve the issue. Can anyone give me a hand? thanks so much.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version 2.

You can set this config by using any of the following methods:

- When you launch your cluster, you can put spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version 2 in the Spark config.
- spark.conf.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version",
  "2")
- When you write data using Dataset API, you can set it in the option, i.e. dataset.write.option("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version",
  "2").

Answer (score 0):

That's the overhead of the commit-by-rename committer having to fake rename by copying and deleting files.

Switch to a higher performance committer, e.g ASF Spark's "zero rename committer" or the EMR clone, "fast spark committer"